# Existing product: how redesign a product of a user only?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, usability-testing, redesign

I participate in a project where "the owner" of the project is also user of it. Overall, it is a project to manage hardware certifications and / or software. The system is scalable and can be used by others.

The issue is that it needs to undergo a process of redesign but I'm out of ideas of how I act to perform some kind of usability testing to be able to propose a new interface / interaction.

Create personas and drive a rapid test usability?
I realize only a heuristic evaluation of the interface that already exists?

Comment: You aim to sell the product to other users or will it continue to be of this single user? The owner asked for a redesign or why it needs to undergo this process?

Comment: If the redesign is a need of the owner doing a requirements interview to understand the needs may help you get a head start. Maybe seeing the current design could make it more clear to give a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips that will help you change your mindset so you can view your product from new perspective:

1. use the six thinking hats method from Ed. De Bono, use Tina Seelig flavour.
2. test the product in a different room / device where you usually test it
3. use the product setting up "extreme scenario" where you tell the user to act according to an extreme scenario you set before hand.